# On real device there is extra space on the side when in game preview there is not

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity and I'm testing it on an Android real device. In the game preview there is no extra spacing on the side

[image]

How ever when I test it on a real device, there ends up to be extra spacing. Why does this happen

Real device - extra spacing...

[image]

Comment: Is your Camera pixel perfect? This may be the problem.

Comment: Pixel Perfect? Sorry what do you mean. I have a Galaxy note 3, but what does the Camera have to do with it? Since I don't need the camera

Comment: I meant your In-game scene's camera. [Why Pixel Perfect is important](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/06/19/pixel-perfect-2d/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to change the aspect ratio in the scene view. To do this simply click on the dropdown button `"Free Aspect"` and try to change the aspect ratio to fit the size/aspect ratio of the android. I would recommend 16:9 as most Android devices use that aspect ratio.